# Representation of a number as a sum of co-prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-functions

### Conventions

We will call the following product the *canonical expansion of $a$*: 
$$a = \prod\limits_{p_i\in\mathbb{P}}p_i^{\alpha_i}.$$

---

If $a$ and $b$ are co-prime we write 
$$a \perp b.$$

### $\beth$-function

Suppose $a\in \mathbb{N}_+$ and $M_k(a)$ is the following set:
$$M_k(a) = \Big\{ (x_1,\ldots,x_k) \Big| \sum x_i = a\quad \mathrm{and}\quad x_i\perp x_j\quad \mathrm{for}\quad i \neq j\Big\}.$$
Then let us construct function (\beth):
$$\beth_k(a) = |M_k(a)|.$$
We choose by definition
$$\beth_k(1) = 1.$$
In other words, $\beth_k(a)$ counts co-prime $k$-partitions of $a$.

---

So my question is to investigate $\beth$-function's properties. The main question, no doubt, is

> Write the explicit (closed form) expression for $\beth_k(a)$ using the canonical expansion of $a$.
>
> ---

Now I am trying to prove that $\beth_k$ is a multiplicative function. More specific, I want to prove that
$$\beth_k(p_1p_2) = \beth_k(p_1)\beth_k(p_2),\quad\forall p_1, p_2\geq k,\, p_1 \perp p_2.$$

Comment: Some empirical observations which might or might not be helpful or deceptive$$\beth_k(k)=1$$
$$\beth_k(k+1)=\beth_k(k+2)=\beth_k(k+4)=k$$
$$\beth_k(k+3)=\beth_k(k+6)=\beth_k(k+8)=k^2$$
$$\beth_k(k+5)=2k^2-k$$
$$\beth_k(k+7)=k^3-k^2+k$$
$$\beth_k(k+9)=2k^3-2k^2+k$$

Comment: (contd.)$$\beth_k(k+10)=k^2$$$$\beth_k(k+11)=2k^3-k^2$$$$\beth_k(k+12)=k^3-k^2+k$$$$\beth_k(k+13)=k^4-2k^3+2k^2$$$$\beth_k(k+14)=3k^2-2k$$

Comment: One has $\beth_{pq}(pq) = 1 \neq 0 = \beth_{pq}(p) \beth_{pq}(q)$ for distinct primes $p,q$. Thus $\beth_{k}$ is not multiplicative in general.

Comment: @js21, Of course $\beth_k(a)$ is define for only $a\geq k$. I will add your remark to the description. P.S, I have tested $\beth_2(n)$ for multiplicity for $n$ up to 100.

Comment: $\beth_2$ is just Euler's totient function. The case $k=2$ is a very special case.

Comment: @js21, I agree. What an obvious fact that I did not note.  Thank you.

Comment: Multiplicativity almost never holds already for $k=3$. E. g. $\beth_3(3)=1$, $\beth_3(4)=3$, $\beth_3(5)=3$, $\beth_3(12)=39$, $\beth_3(20)=93$.